# GCP Billing Frontend Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wanted to play a bit with GCP. I have deployed two services:

- Spring Boot Java app (simple CRUD) (called api)
- React auto-generated app (no changes at all, just POC) (called default)

So, after deploy I made a couple of request to my React app and I was able to see spinning react welcome banner. Hurray! I left project at it was.

After one day (Saturday, 25th) I have received first invoice. Claiming 40 hours of Frontend instance. Screen below. App was deployed at Friday 24th, 1PM. I cannot see any other requests than initial ones.

[image: Summary of requests]

It is a 4 or 5 days later now and I'm still being charged every day. After 2 days I **disabled both apps** (not a project).

[image]

Even after disabling both apps, Fronted Instance hours keep increasing. GCP claims 184 hours at this moment.

[image]

Forecasted total cost is always 0.0.

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

According to App Engine [instance billing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_billing),

> *instances are charged per-minute for their uptime*

Since the App Engine is already disabled, the instances should be zero and stop the instance billing. Verify this further by:

- Go to App Engine > Versions
- **Instances** must be **0**. If they are still more than 0, you can open this as an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=1162848)

The *Forecasted total cost* will always be zero because you still have free credits / promotions. Once these credits are used up, the reflected costs will change.